# A combinatorial identity involving $m^n$.

Tags: combinatorics

While solving a combinatorial problem I came across an interesting identity.

Let $\mathbf{k}=\{k_0,k_1,k_2\dots\} $ be an ordered set of non-negative integer numbers and let ${\cal K}_m^n$ be a set of $\mathbf{k}$ such that:
$$
\mathbf{k}\in {\cal K}_m^n\Leftrightarrow\sum_{i\ge0}k_i=m,\sum_{i\ge0}i k_i=n. \tag{1}
$$

Then the following summation identity applies:
$$
\sum_{\mathbf{k}\in {\cal K}_m^n}\frac{m!n!}{\displaystyle\prod_{i\ge0}(i!)^{k_i}k_i!}=m^n.\tag{2}
$$

Is there a simple way to prove it? Combinatorial and non-combinatorial proofs are of equal interest.

The question is related to the [previous one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2665048/293846), where the combinatorial meaning of the problem and cardinality of the set ${\cal K}_m^n$ is clarified.

Comment: Is this question related to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2665048/sum-i-k-i-k-sum-i-i-k-i-n?

Comment: I recommend highlighting the connection to the earlier Question by including a link in the body of this Question, and ideally explaining the connection in more detail than given here.

Comment: @hardmath Done. Besides the previous question is updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is simply the multinomial theorem after sorting the lower indices:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{\substack{\sum\limits_{j\ge0}k_j=m\\\sum\limits_{j\ge0}jk_j=n}}\overbrace{\binom{n}{\underbrace{0,0,\dots}_{k_0\text{times}},\,\underbrace{1,1,\dots}_{k_1\text{times}},\,\dots}}^{\text{lower indices sorted}}\overbrace{\binom{m}{k_0,\,k_1,\,\cdots}}^{\substack{\text{number of ways}\\\text{to arrange the}\\\text{lower indices}\\\text{ in the preceding}\\\text{multinomial}}}
&=\sum_{\sum\limits_{j=1}^ma_j=n}\overbrace{\binom{n}{a_1,\,a_2,\,\cdots,\, a_m}}^{\text{lower indices unsorted}}1^{a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_m}\\
&=(\overbrace{1+1+\cdots+1}^{\text{$m$ copies}})^n
\end{align}
$$
That is, since the order of the $a_j$'s doesn't matter in $\binom{n}{a_1,\,a_2,\,\cdots,\, a_m}$, on the left side, we sort the $a_j$'s into $k_0$ $0$'s, $k_1$ $1$'s, etc. and compute that multinomial coefficient and then multiply by the number of equal multinomials on the right (from rearrangements of the $a_j$'s) which is $\binom{m}{k_0,\,k_1,\,\cdots}$.

Comment: I think that the factorial sign should be removed from multinomial coefficients.

Comment: @RobertZ: you're absolutely right.

Comment: It is of course clear that the LHS of the expression (2) in question is the sum of products of two multinomials. The only problem is to demonstrate the equivalence of both sums. It seems that some transformation is missed which would explain a connection between "left" and "right" $k's$. Besides the term "sorted lower indices" being applied to a multinomial seems to be misleading, as its value does not depend on the order of the indices, does it?

Comment: @user: Of course the order of the lower indices does not matter; that is why we can multiply one multinomial coefficient with sorted lower indices by the number of permutations of the lower indices to get the total of all unsorted orders of the lower indices. For example: $$\underbrace{\binom{2}{0,1,1}}_{\text{sorted lower indices}}\ \ \underbrace{\ \binom{3}{1,2}\ }_{\substack{\text{number of permutations}\\\text{of lower indices}}}=\underbrace{\binom{2}{0,1,1}+\binom{2}{1,0,1}+\binom{2}{1,1,0}}_{\text{unsorted lower indices}}$$

Comment: It looks very nice and understandable. However in this example the indices in the leftmost multinomial and in the multinomials on the RHS are the same. In the final expression you gave they seem however to be different. They are certainly not the same $k's$ as in the LHS. It would be very helpful if you clarify the point, especially the fact that there are exactly $m$ RHS-$k$'s and they run over all possible values allowed by the restrictions $k_i\ge0$ and $\sum_i k_i=n$.

Comment: @user: The example above is the case $\mathbf{k}=(1,2,0)$ of $\cal{K}_3^2$. We get all of the possible $m$-tuples of lower indices on the right because we get all the sorted $m$-tuples of lower indices on the left with their multiplicities.

Comment: Now I see what you mean. I believe it would be very helpful to put these details into the answer. Besides I would suggest to replace the $k$'s in RHS with $j$, or in some other way to underline that they are directly related to the *indices* of $k_j$ on LHS. In any case the usage of $k$'s on RHS is misleading (I recognize of course that mathematically it is irrelevant).

Comment: @user: I have made some changes. Is that better?

Comment: I have no further suggestions on the improving the answer and accept it as understandable for me. I cannot be sure that others also will understand everything in the argumentation.

Answer (score 3):

A combinatorial proof. The integer
$$\frac{m!n!}{\displaystyle\prod_{i\ge0}(i!)^{k_i}k_i!}=\binom{m}{k_0,k_1,\dots}\cdot \binom{n}{\underbrace{0,\dots,0}_{k_0},\underbrace{1,\dots,1}_{k_1},\dots,\underbrace{i,\dots,i}_{k_i},\dots}$$
counts the number of functions $f$ from $N:=\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ to $M:=\{1,2,\dots,m\}$ such that for any non negative integer $i$,
$$k_i=\left|\left\{j\in M:|f^{-1}(j)|=i\right\}\right|.$$
where $|S|$ denotes the cardinality of the set $S$.

Finally note that $m^n$ is the total number of functions from $N$ to $M$.
Hence
$$\sum_{\mathbf{k}\in {\cal K}_m^n}
\frac{m!n!}{\displaystyle\prod_{i\ge0}(i!)^{k_i}k_i!}=m^n.$$

For example, for $m=n=3$, ${\cal K}_3^3=\{(2,0,0,1),(1,1,1), (0,3)\}$ and 
$$\frac{3!\cdot 3!}{(0!)^2(1!)^0(2!)^0(3!)^1 2! 0! 0! 1!}+\frac{3!\cdot 3!}{(0!)^1(1!)^1(2!)^1 1! 1! 1!}
+\frac{3!\cdot 3!}{(0!)^0(1!)^30! 3!}=3+18+6=3^3.$$

Comment: Could you add some words to clarify the expression for $k_i$?

Comment: I am quite sure that the identity is valid independent from condition $k_i\ne k_j$.

Comment: @user Yes you are correct. Any further doubt?

Comment: I have no doubts that your approach is correct, but have some problems with understanding what kind of functions counts a single term of the sum and why it is a product of the multinomials.

Comment: In my final example $3$ is the number of constant functions (see $(2,0,0,1)$) and $6$ is the number of bijective functions (see $(0,3)$). Is this fact clear? $(1,2,3)\to(3,1,1)$ is one of the remaining $18$ functions with  $|f^{-1}(2)|=0$, $|f^{-1}(3)|=1$, $|f^{-1}(1)|=2$ (see $(1,1,1)$).

Comment: I believe it can be useful if you add this example to the answer and explain its connection to the product of multinomials.