# Are there any power identities which don't belong to this list?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, soft-question, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

The problem of finding expansions of monomials, binomials etc. is classical and there is a lot of beautiful solutions have been found already, the most prominent examples are

**Binomial Theorem, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem).**

*For every* $(a,b,n)\in\mathbb{N}$
$$(a+b)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}a^k b^{n-k},$$
and for monomials could be written as
$$m^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\sum_{j=0}^{k}\binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{j}(-1)^{k-j}m^j.$$

It also follows an identity in binomials to [Falling Factorial power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials)
$$(x+y)^\underline{n} = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} x^\underline{k} y^\underline{n-k}$$

**Multinomial Theorem, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem). (Partial Case)**

*For every* $(m,n)\in\mathbb{N}$
$$m^{n}=\sum _{k_{1}+k_{2}+\cdots +k_{m}=n}{n \choose k_{1},k_{2},\ldots ,k_{m}},$$
where ${n \choose k_{1},k_{2},\ldots ,k_{m}}$ is Multinomial coefficient.

**Faulhaber's Formula, [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9207222), pp. 9-10.**

*For every* $(m,n)\in\mathbb{N}$
$$n^{2m-1} = \sum_{k=1}^{m} (2k-1)!T(2m,2k) \binom{n+k-1}{2k-1},$$
where $T(2m,2k)$ are [Central Factorial Numbers](https://oeis.org/A008955).

**Worpitzky Identity, [https://eudml.org/doc/148532](http://eudml.org/doc/148532).**

*For every* $(m,n)\in\mathbb{N}$
$$m^n = \sum_{k=0}^{n} E_{n,k} \binom{m+k}{n},$$
where $E_{n,k}$ are [Eulerian Numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerianNumber.html).

**Identity between Stirling numbers of the second kind and falling factorial**

*For every* $(x,n)\in\mathbb{N}$
$$x^n=\sum _{{k=0}}^{n}\left\{{n \atop k}\right\}(x)_{k},$$ 
where $\left\{{n \atop k}\right\}$ are [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) and $(x)_{k}$ is [Falling factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials).

Also the one good example can be found at Wolfram Mathworld, so-called

**MacMillan Double Binomial Sum, [Wolfram MathWorld, "Power", eq. 12](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Power.html)**.

*For every* $(x,n)\in\mathbb{N}$
$$x^n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{k}(-1)^{k-j}\binom{k}{j}\binom{x}{k}j^n.$$

Proof of MacMillan identity is discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3176698).

**Result from question [2669237](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2669237)**.
$$m^n=\sum_{\mathbf{k}\in {\cal K}_m^n}\frac{m!n!}{\displaystyle\prod_{i\ge0}(i!)^{k_i}k_i!},$$
see the link in title for the explanations.

**Ascending Bases and Exponents in Pascal's Triangle, [Cut the Knot](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/combinatorics/PascalTriangleProperties.shtml)**.
$$(n+1)^j=\frac{j!\prod_{k=0}^j\binom{n+k}{k}}{\prod_{k=0}^{j-1}\binom{n+1+k}{k}}$$

**Pascal's identity, [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1011.0076).**
$$(n+1)^{k+1}-1=\sum_{m=1}^{n}[(m+1)^{k+1}-m^{k+1}]=\sum_{p=0}^{k}\binom{k+1}{p}(1^p+2^p+\cdots+n^p),$$

---

***Question:*** Are there any other power identites, which not in the list above ?

Comment: I think questions 1 and 2 should be separate posts.

Comment: Good idea and its done

Answer (score 1):

***Question 1:*** Certainly there are other identities, for example the [following one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2669237): 
$$
m^n=\sum_{k_i\ge0}^{\sum_i k_i=m\atop\sum_i ik_i=n}\frac{m!n!}{\displaystyle\prod_{i\ge0}(i!)^{k_i}k_i!}.
$$